# get files from s3 and upload as zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to upload the same folder as zip in the existing s3 bucket.

```
ex:
s3->infinate (folder)

output:
s3->infinate.zip
```

Here is my python code:

```
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zipper:
     for pkg_obj in s3.get_folder_summary(s3_bucket, s3_key):
         infile_object = s3.get_s3_object(s3_bucket, pkg_obj.key)
         infile_content = infile_object['Body'].read()
         zipper.writestr(pkg_obj.key, infile_content)
         s3.upload_file_in_temp_location(infile_content, s3_bucket, pkg_obj.key+".zip")
```

But I was unable to upload the zip folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was unable to upload the zip file in the s3 bucket